# Как получить первую цифру многозначного числа?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно, чтобы код остановился на первой цифре многозначного целочисленного числа.
Что надо добавить?

```
n = int(input())
while n // 10 != 0:
   n = n // 10
```

Comment: Сейчас не останавливается? Или что?

Comment: `на первой цифре многозначного целочисленного числа` это 10, например? Или любое число у которого больше одного разряда?

Comment: Дано например число 178, нужно чтобы программа запомнила 1 а остальное отбросила, а сейчас в этом коде она до конца идет и оставляет только 0

Comment: `while n >= 10:` (`assert n >= 0`)

Answer (score 2):

Переводим модуль числа (на случай отрицательных чисел) в текст и берем первый символ:

```
 n = str(abs(chislo))[0]
```

Если результат нужно использовать как число, то конвертируем строку опять в число:

```
n = int(str(abs(chislo))[0])
```

Comment: Для отрицательных чисел это будет минус?

Comment: @andreymal Ага. Но исправить легко. Подправил.

Answer (score 1):

```
n = -50178

sign = False

if n < 0:
    n *= -1
    sign = True

while n >= 10:
    n //= 10

if sign:
    n *= -1

print(n)  # -5
```

Comment: "-5" не цифра, а число.

Comment: Если хочется использовать дополнительную переменную, то ``sign = abs(n) == n`` заменяет четыре строчки одной.

Comment: @Эникейщик главное, чтобы автор вопроса понимал, что делает код, а улучшать его можно до бесконечности. Цель - показать рабочий пример. Убрать знак несложно.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input())
while n > 9:
    n = n // 10
print(n)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input())  # вводимое число

while n != 0:  # цикл работает, пока в числе есть цифры
    last_digit = n % 10  # каждую итерацию получаем последнюю цифру числа
    
    # код обработки последней цифры
    n = n // 10  # удалить последнюю цифру из числа

print(n)  # выводим последнюю оставшуюся цифру (она и будет первой цифрой числа)
```

Comment: Вы проверили свой ответ?